# Possible for there to be same street, city, and country in two locations

Tags: geocoding, reverse-geocoding, address, mapping

I am working on a project, and need to know if it is at all likely in most of the world that there can be two streets in a city with the same name, in the same country, but in two different locations.

Eg. Example Street, Chicago, USA & Example Street, Chicago, USA. These would be different streets. It doesn't matter to me if they have different address numbers on them.

Is this likely in the USA or Europe?

Comment: Quite possible....Portland Oregon and Portland Maine ... are there two Main streets?

Comment: What about something like "Main St" and "Main Rd"? Are you referring to just the street *name* or also its *suffix*?

Comment: What about a Shady Lane and a Shady Lane in Beaumont, Texas. Is this allowed? They do have two different zip codes 77706 & 77713. However, they each are in the same County and same City.

Answer (score 1):

Just about anything is possible in street naming. You can get duplicate streets, streets that are unique because of the direction they travel (e.g. lots of streets in Washington DC), numbers for the same street that reset when you cross into different areas.

Personal example - trying to find a hotel at 2am (after flights from Australia via Sydney, LAX and JFK): 35 Middlesex Turnpike, Billerica, Massachusetts, 01821-3936, USA . But the bit of Middlesex Turnpike you need for that Hotel isn't actually in Billerica - its in Bedford. Its such a common problem that the hotel's website (now) tells you to use Bedford...

Wikipedia on Boston road names: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transportation_in_Boston#Road_infrastructure and how this problem occurs.

Examples from Ottowa (that were corrected): http://ottawa.ca/en/residents/laws-licenses-and-permits/building-and-renovating/e

Deptford duplication: http://articles.philly.com/1994-02-07/news/25858602_1_house-fire-postal-address-emergency

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I can give you many examples from Budapest, Hungary. Here we have 10 Kossuth Lajos Streets, 10 Baross Streets, but the winner is Zrínyi Street, as there are 12 of it in Budapest!

To understand why this is, you have to know the history of our capital city. Budapest was founded in 1873 when 3 cities, Pest, Buda and Óbuda were united. Then they renamed all the streets with the same name so there was only one Kossuth Lajos Street, one Baross Street and one Zrínyi Street in the city, and so on, there were no duplicates between the borders of the city. If they wanted to give a street a new name, it had to be one that hadn't already existed. However, the city was extended in 1950, 7 towns and 16 villages from Pest county were attached to Budapest!
They didn't want to rename all the streets with the same name in this huge metropolis that was born in that year, so they created a new law which says that there can be streets with the same name in the city but only in different districts. Of course they got different post codes later, that's how you can distinguish them or with the number of the districts.
But this can sometimes be confusing. 
For example, once I had to go to Márvány Street in Budapest, and the post code that was given to me was 1121. So I went to 1121 Márvány Street, which is in district 12. But later I found out that the post code was not correct, the place I was looking for was in district 21 with the code of 1211. So I was in Márvány Street, but in the wrong one, the one I should've gone to was 5 kilometres away in district 21, which is rather in the suburb than in the city centre. That was just because two numbers in the post code they gave me were swapped.
But normally if you know the code and the district correctly, you can find the street you are looking for easily.

Answer (score 0):

Quite certain that this happend somehwere in the world, specially when it comes to larger cities. Though then officials probably make sure that the streets fall into different postal codes.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly pertaining to the specificity you have outlined though: 
I live on a ”Road” which is 9km in length & extends through 8 different suburbs. The numbers 1 - 200 have been used  @ both ends of the road so despite being in different suburbs & therefore having different Zip codes, there are multiple locations on the same street with the same number.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. There are at least 4 streets with this name SE 258TH STREET in the small town of COVINGTON in WASHINGTON state. They are all in the same zip code as well. I have mapped them for you.

https://goo.gl/maps/WQ1TiTWhRndDYfC29

https://goo.gl/maps/riM9braW8Hh82KGE7

https://goo.gl/maps/r3goofFkDoxdTGTx5

https://goo.gl/maps/m3wpA8sr1FhzAWXb6

One thing that *seems* to be common, is that they all *appear* to be in the same latitude.

Now, can someone help understand why or how the streets are numbered, especially in the pacific NW, that would be super.

Is this what the OP is looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that can happen is when the same street exists in two locations...the "pieces" are close to each other, but they do not connect. You could very easily consider this to be 2 different streets with the same name, but the town considers it the same street, especially regarding the consecutive numbering of houses. This happens with Maple St. in Danvers, Massachusetts where I live, but I've seen it other places too. Usually the "extra" piece is small compared to the entire street, and there's some sort of historical re-routing that caused this to occur.